# jQuery Mobile Button being fired on next page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am writing a jQuery Mobile/Phonegap application that has multiple pages with buttons in the header. When two pages have buttons in the same place and are linked to each other the button on the page that is linked is fired as soon as the page comes into view. I have only noticed this issues when trying to update from 1.0b1 to 1.0.1 or 1.1.0. I am running Android 2.3.3.

I have looked everywhere and haven't been able to find anyone having this same issue. Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem on Android that has not been fixed. I usually just override the default "tap" event for Android button presses to use a "click" event instead... I struggled with this for a while and did not find a better solution. The click event seems to work more reliably on Android!

I usually check the user agent when I set up my button press events in an init function:

```
var init = function() {
    // Check the user agent
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var isAndroid = ua.indexOf('android') > -1;
    if(isAndroid) {
        d.delegate($('#yourButtonID', 'click', onYourButtonTapped);
    } else {
        d.delegate($('#yourButtonID', 'tap', onYourButtonTapped);
    }
};

var onYourButtonTapped = function() {
    // your code here
};
```